# What could possibly go wrong if a laptop was kept in a kitchen?

Tags: laptop, physical-environment

I have the need to place a laptop in a restaurant's kitchen, but I'm worried that the cooking smells would stick to it and make it less pleasant (and possibly unhygienic) to use. This kitchen will occasionally grill/barbecue meat and when it does so it makes a whole lot of smoke.

In order to comply with local laws I had to "isolate" the laptop from the kitchen, so that it won't stand in the way nor pose any danger to those who occupy it or to the food being cooked, however the only place where this could happen was near one of the two air extractors, specifically one that just seems to take odors and a minimal amount of smoke (going on the other side I can notice the kitchen's smell, but can't see any smoke coming out of it).

My questions is: what could possibly go wrong with that setup? Will the air flow (which happens to "hit the laptop" at some point) make the laptop sticky and/or smelly? Will the smoke and vapors damage it? And if so, is there anything I could do to mitigate this? I know that cigarette smoke is (arguably) dangerous to a PC, but I don't know if that's because of cigarette specific chemicals or smoke in general... Please bear in mind that this is an ordinary laptop, no rugged water-proof or dust-proof stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Depends a lot on the kitchen, but off the top of my head are:
- Spills
- Grease
- Central point for bacteria transfers

Spills should be self-explanatory. Avoid it, that's it.

If my kitchen is an indication, your laptop might build up grease, as it passes the kitchen air inside it. However, I'm sure your kitchen is a lot better ventilated than my dungeonesque cooking central. In terms of being sticky, I would think that this is likely to happen over time, but this can probably be reduced with various methods. I have seen restaurants and the like wrap computery equipment in cellophane plastic, including a thin layer over the keyboard. Just make sure you don't cover up any vents.

I'm sure you know more about bacteria transfers and all that than I do, but an advantage to the cellophane method above is that it makes cleaning with alcohol a lot easier.

I think that the biggest concern is grease building up in the dust filter and clogging it. Consider monitoring temperatures and fan speeds. If these go astray, you might have to clean out or replace the filter. If this becomes a problem, you should perhaps have this as a part of the periodic cleaning schedule that I'm sure you have in some shape or form.

As a footnote I would like to mention that: Yes, cigarette smoke is dangerous. But I used to be a chainsmoking programmer (Now I'm neither), and I have never had a computer fail because of this. So I think that while it's far from healthy for the computer, most computers can handle it. I would think kitchen fumes aren't any worse, unless it's very humid and greasy.

Comment: And high humidity is really bad for computers

Comment: @Moab I used to work on a ship, it very warm and humid areas. We had a computer that was left running on deck in 100% humidity for testing-purposes, and it lasted 2 months - A lot more than any of us anticipated.

Comment: I remember the days when they sold temp and humidity gauges to set on top of your office server.....